# javascript, if input from user is correct goto x subpage

Tags: javascript, html

So i want to add to my page a script that would transfer a user after x input to subpage assigned to this input.

Comment: try reading about how to get value from textbox into javascript.

Comment: you got your problem solved?

Comment: Oh yea, thanks for help, unfortunately it seems like i don't have enough reputation to give a vote up. Although i'm having problems with window.location, it doesn't really work for me but i guess i just need to read about it and eventually i'll  manage.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<form>
Password: <input type="text" name="password" id='txtPassword'>
<button id='btnSubmit'>Submit</button></form>
<script>
    var submit = document.getElementById('btnSubmit')
    submit.onclick = function () {
        var password = document.getElementById('txtPassword').value;
        if (condition1)
        {
           goes to a subpage1
        }
        else if (condition2)
        {
          goes to a subpage1
        }
        else
        {
          alert with some message
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So, you read the password immediately after loading the page? Doesn't sound like a good solution.

Comment: oh dear. My Bad. that should happen on click of a submit button. Will edit accordingly..

Comment: @dusky Thanks a lot. That just slipped out of my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a button :

```
<form>
 Password: <input type="text" name="password">
 <button onclick="checkPass();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now in JS

```
<script>

function checkPass(){
  var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
  if ( password != "") //or any condition
  {
     window.location.href = 'page_1_url' ; //goes to a subpage1
  }
  else if (condition2) //...
  {
    window.location.href = 'page_2_url' ; //goes to a subpage1
  }
  else
  {
    alert('....') ; //alert with some message
  }
}
```